# Why the “à” in “Je n’avais pas à m’excuser”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I know what the sentence *Je n’avais pas m’excuser* means. At least I’m highly convinced it means something like:

> I’m not gonna say sorry.

But why the *à* here ? I know it means something like ‘at’ or ‘towards’, but shouldn’t you need to use something like *à lui* ?

[image: picture of the book]
The book I'm reading, in which I came across this sentence, is called *L’Étranger* by Albert Camus

Answer (score 6):

*[Avoir à](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0)* means *must*, *have to*. The construction is similar to the English *have to*, and in this particular sentence it works as a translation, although I think a better translation would be “In summary, I didn't need to apologize”.

*Avoir à* + verbe is mostly used in negative sentences: “*Je n'ai pas à faire cela*” = “I don't have to do this”. “*Ne pas avoir à …*” means that the action is not compulsory. There is also a related construction *Avoir* + nom + *à* + verbe which doesn't have this restriction: “*J'ai quelque chose à faire*” = “I have something to do”, expressing a moral or practical obligation or even something that one wants to do.

The equivalent of ”I'm not going to apologize“ would be “*Je ne vais pas m'excuser*”. The equivalent of ”I wasn't going to apologize“ would be “*Je n'allais pas m'excuser*”. “*<s>*Je n’avais pas m’excuser*</s>” is not a French sentence. “*Je ne m'étais pas excusé*” would be “I didn't apologize”.